# Is there any way to forward Kafka messages from topic on one server to topic on another server?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a scenario where we are forwarding our application logs to Kafka topic using fluentD agents,
as Kafka team introduced Kerberos authentication and fluentD version not supporting this authentication, I cannot directly use forward logs.
Now we have introduced a new Kafka server without authentication and created a topic there, I want forward messages from this topic in the new server to another topic in another server using Kafka connectors, 
want to know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

There's several different tools that enable you to stream messages from a Kafka topic on one cluster to a different cluster, including:

- [MirrorMaker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330)  (open source, part of Apache Kafka)
- Confluent's [Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html) (commercial tool, 30 day free trial)
- [uReplicator](https://github.com/uber/uReplicator) ([open sourced](https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/) from Uber)
- [Mirus](https://github.com/salesforce/mirus) ([open sourced](https://engineering.salesforce.com/open-sourcing-mirus-3ec2c8a38537) from Salesforce)
- [Brucke](https://github.com/klarna/brucke) (open source)

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: From what I can find looking over sources/issues of the open source projects, it seems only Replicator will copy over the topic configs along with just the data like all the others. Correct me if I'm wrong.